# R Server how to download a package with dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I am trying to download a package with dependencies but i am not able to figure out the dependencies option or command. Below is working to download the package to a folder.

download.packages("A3", repos ="http://cran.rstudio.com/", destdir = "/tmp/download/A3")

how can i download the dependencies to the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tools::package_dependencies("A3")` to get the list of dependencies of the package.

To download them all, you can use :

```
library(tools)
lapply(package_dependencies("A3"), 
       download.packages, 
          repos ="http://cran.rstudio.com/", 
          destdir = "/tmp/download/A3")
```

Comment: Thank you but get this error
> lapply(package_dependencies("A3"),
+        download.packages,
+           repos ="http://cran.rstudio.com/",
+           destdir = "/tmp/download/A3")
Error in lapply(package_dependencies("A3"), download.packages, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/",  :
  could not find function "package_dependencies"
>

Comment: try with `library(tools)`

Comment: os instead of lapply you are saying to try library(tools)? Thanks

Comment: no load `tools` before calling `package_dependencies`